# How to align card-images next to each other in react native

Tags: javascript, css, ios, reactjs, react-native

I just started with react native, I wanted to align card images next to each other (react-native-elements) but it does not work for some reason. What I want to achieve is two rows in on phones and 3 rows on tablets. But for some reason my code does not work. First the cards are aligned connected to each other no space between them and on my phone (Iphone 12) it is aligned as a column. Even though I have set flex-direction to row. could someone look at my code and tell me what is wrong?

card-image element

```
<View style={styles.secondPartOfDisplay}>
        {categories.map((c,i) => {
          return (
                <View key={i} style={{width: 200, height: 150, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                  <Card.Image >
                <Image
                    style={{width:200,height:150}}
                    resizeMode="cover"
                    source={c.imageSource}
              />
                  </Card.Image>

                </View>
          )
        })}

      </View>
```

styles:

```
secondPartOfDisplay: {
    paddingTop: 30,
    display:'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    justifyContent: "space-between"
  },
```

And here is the image on how it looks on phone:

[image: Iphone 12 look]

This is how it looks on ipad:

[image: this is how it looks on ipad]

Answer (score 0):

If there iis no extra margin or padding that's messing with your container grid, then probably your images are not responsive according to the screen size. You would probably need to set your image `height: "100%"` and `width: "auto"`
Hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply at the same time I am overseas right now. I tried what you said but the images disappear completely if I do that. I put it inside the style tag of the image

Comment: Would be better if you could share a [Codepen link](https://codepen.io/pen/)